# MySQL connection fails because of invalid link resource

Tags: php, mysql

My Code:

```
class cdbsHandler
{
    [...]
    private $link;

    function __construct($mysqld)
    {
        [...]

        $this->link = mysql_connect(
            $mysqld['host'], $mysqld['user'], $mysqld['password']
        );

        mysql_select_db($mysqld['database'], $this->link);  
    }

    function write($sessionId, $data)
    {
        $sessionId = mysql_real_escape_string($sessionId, $this->link);
    }
    [...]
}
```

I use the class like this:

```
static function startSession($name, $mysqld)
{
    [...]
    $sessionHandler = new cdbsHandler($mysqld);
    session_set_save_handler(
        array ($sessionHandler,"open"),
        array ($sessionHandler,"close"),array ($sessionHandler,"read"),
        array ($sessionHandler,"write"),array ($sessionHandler,"destroy"),
        array ($sessionHandler,"gc")
    );
    session_start();
}
```

Where `$mysqld` are the database credentials.
The static function is called every time that a user loads a page.

The error I get is:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(): 2 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource 
(calling mysql_real_escape_string in the write function)
```

The credentials are correct. They are loaded from a config file and are successfully used to establish a connection a few lines after the session was started.

**What seems very important to me:**
I am actually able to login and data is written to the database (/session) but as soon as the login page redirects me to the home page the error mentioned above appears.
(The login page verifies a form token that is saved in the session data. But after sending that request the script isn't able to access any session data anymore.)

**More Information:**
The code is from a memcached session handler with database "backup".

Comment: I feel like we're missing a lot of code here, can you please provide more of the code so we can see where the issue lies? For example where and how is the `write()` function/`$sessionId` variable being used?

Comment: Are you sure the database connection completed successfully? Try adding `or die(mysql_error())` after the `mysql_connect()` call.

Comment: @Ryan: It is used when I write to sessions and the sessionId is automatically passed to the function by php.

Comment: @MichaelMior: Yes I am sure. I am able to query the database within the __construct() function without any problems.

Comment: As an aside, you should be fine with just `mysql_escape_string` since all default session IDs are alphanumeric.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is what's happening (best guess based on your information):

Per [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) the session write handler is not called until after the script has ended. In many versions of PHP, all class destructors are run *before* calling the session write handler. Consequently, if you are closing the connection in __destruct(), then __destruct() is called before write() is - leading to an invalid connection when you  try to save the session.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am not using a __destruct function but it might have to do something with it. Any idea how to ensure that the connection is still available?

Comment: Nothing very clean - either explicitly close the session everywhere (session_write_close) or (re)connect before writing the session (ewww).